# how to change form for support and resistance in cufflink's quantfig?

Tags: python, plotly-dash

In cufflink's QuantFig,for support and resistance lines, the documentation seems to only provide horizontal lines. Could we use other forms such as using moving average as barriers?  The below documentation is not clear. anyone has experience with that changing to different form for support and resistance line like below 2nd plot?

https://jpoles1.github.io/cufflinks/html/_modules/cufflinks/quant_figure.html#QuantFig.add_resistance

```
# Creating QuantFig object
qf = cf.QuantFig(df, kind='candlestick', name='data', legend='top')

# Adding a resistance level
qf.add_resistance(date='2015-02-17', on='close', color='orange')

# Adding a support level
qf.add_support(date='2015-01-28', on='low', color='blue')

# Plotting
qf.iplot(theme='white', up_color='green', down_color='red')
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Cufflinks provides functions to directly add a moving agerage study to the QuantFigure, both SMA and EMA are implemented :

- [`QuantFig.add_sma()`](https://jpoles1.github.io/cufflinks/html/cufflinks.quant_figure.html#cufflinks.quant_figure.QuantFig.add_sma)
- [`QuantFig.add_ema()`](https://jpoles1.github.io/cufflinks/html/cufflinks.quant_figure.html#cufflinks.quant_figure.QuantFig.add_ema)

eg. Simple moving average (with defaults parameter) on 'GE' :

[image: SMA example (GE)]

Comment: Thanks Eric, I knew these function, sorry for confusing. I just added 2nd figure which was what I wanted to do.

Comment: Ah ok makes sense, sorry I don't know how to do that..